# How to create a regex pattern to remove line breaks after specific tag

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove one line breaks in every ending of `{literal}` tag?

I tried using this regex pattern `(?<=\{literal\}|\{\/literal\}\s)\s+` but the problem of this is it didn't preserve the spaces or tab. For example below

```
<script>
    {literal}

    (function () {
        //カレンダー
        var now = 0;

        $(window).on('load', function () {
            abc();
            $('.holiday').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val === '') {
                    $(this).removeClass('holiday');
                }
            });
        });

        $('#next').on('click', function () {
            now++;
            abc(now);
        });

        $('#prev').on('click', function () {
            now--;
            abc(now);
        });
    })();


{/literal}
</script>
```

```
<script src="/scripts/pc_functions.js"></script>

<!-- YTM -->
<script type="text/javascript">{literal}
        (function () {
            var tagjs = document.createElement("script");
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            tagjs.async = true;
            tagjs.src = "//s.yjtag.jp/tag.js#site=mOjVJxB,c30x29r,64JeBvp,WvJI3VS,mqotrsJ,KJG7ewD,vcS2YQh,DOhPuhc";
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(tagjs, s);
        }()); {/literal}
</script>
<noscript>
    {literal}<iframe src="//b.yjtag.jp/iframe?c=mOjVJxB,c30x29r,64JeBvp,WvJI3VS,mqotrsJ,KJG7ewD,vcS2YQh" width="1"
        height="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>{/literal}
</noscript>
```

This is what I want to achieve

```
<script>
    {literal}
    (function () {
        //カレンダー
        var now = 0;

        $(window).on('load', function () {
            abc();
            $('.holiday').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val === '') {
                    $(this).removeClass('holiday');
                }
            });
        });

        $('#next').on('click', function () {
            now++;
            abc(now);
        });

        $('#prev').on('click', function () {
            now--;
            abc(now);
        });
    })();


{/literal}</script>
```

```
<script src="/scripts/pc_functions.js"></script>

<!-- YTM -->
<script type="text/javascript">{literal}        (function () {
            var tagjs = document.createElement("script");
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            tagjs.async = true;
            tagjs.src = "//s.yjtag.jp/tag.js#site=mOjVJxB,c30x29r,64JeBvp,WvJI3VS,mqotrsJ,KJG7ewD,vcS2YQh,DOhPuhc";
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(tagjs, s);
        }()); {/literal}
</script>
<noscript>
    {literal}<iframe src="//b.yjtag.jp/iframe?c=mOjVJxB,c30x29r,64JeBvp,WvJI3VS,mqotrsJ,KJG7ewD,vcS2YQh" width="1"
        height="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>{/literal}</noscript>
```

Comment: Have you tried rtrim? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: Try `(\{\/?literal\}\h*)(\R)+` and replace with `$1$2` (`preg_replace('~(\{/?literal\}\h*)(\R)+~', '$1$2', $s)`), see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/L5Yxz2/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Thank you but it only resolve this problem 
```
<script>
    {literal}

    (function () {
        //カレンダー
        var now = 0;
```
others like 
`<script type="text/javascript">{literal}`

should be

`<script type="text/javascript">{literal}        (function () {`

Comment: @bobblebubble still doesn't achieve what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well:

```
$str = preg_replace('~{/?literal}\K\h*\R~', '', $str);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/RpWvOy/1)